# Шаблон регулярного выражения в awk

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, linux

Есть скрипт вида

```
awk '/before[a-z]+after/{print > ?? ".txt" }' filename
```

Вместо ?? требуется получить распознанное значение шаблона [a-z]+, так чтобы имя файла равнялось этому значению.

Как этого добиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не так?

```
    awk '{if (match($0, /before([a-z]+)after/, a)) {print a[1]}}'
```

Однако очередной зашифрованный вопрос...

Answer (score 1):

```
...print > $1...

[s@pandora6 20130303]$ cat qwert.txt

beforeaaaaafter
beforebbbaaaaafter
beforeaacccaaafter
beforeassssaaaafter

[s@pandora6 20130303]$ awk '/before[a-z]+after/{print > $1 ".txt" }' qwert.txt

[s@pandora6 20130303]$ ls -t1r

beforebbbaaaaafter.txt
beforeassssaaaafter.txt
beforeaacccaaafter.txt
beforeaaaaafter.txt
```

Не знаю, зачем вам это.. но вроде так ))

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что в awk можно воспользоваться стандартными обратными ссылками (**backreferences**). Возьмите [a-z]+ в скобки (получится группа) и по номеру группы можно получить её содержание с помощью \{номер группы}

Итого, должно получится что-то вроде

```
awk '/before([a-z]+)after/{print > \1 ".txt" }' filename
```

Comment: Нельзя насколько я знаю

Answer (score 0):

Кому интересно, получилось через gawk:

```
cat filename | gawk 'match($0, /before([a-z]+)after/, x) {print $0 > x[1] ".txt" }'
```

Comment: То же хотел предложить, не успел :)  
gawk и match

Comment: @ReinRaus а где водится не гнусный awk?

Comment: @alexlz, не понял вопроса

Comment: @ReinRaus awk, который не gnu awk, т.е. gawk

Comment: У меня такой на бубунте. Например команда из этого ответа на awk выдаст синтаксическую ошибку, а gawk выполнится и выдаст результат, что говорит о том, что awk не GNUшный.

Comment: @ReinRaus Ну вообще-то все (??) гнусные продукты отзываются на ключ `--version`

Comment: @alexlz, действительно. Ввел:  

    awk --version
выдало, что он GNU